# .png or .jpg image moving across the screen, spritesheet, css keyframe, stopping and repeating the cycle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Does anyone know how to stop a css keyframe rotational/circular motion with using .png or .jpg image to move the image and then instead of looping it infinitely, it would have to come to a stop after some time has passed?

Bascially, there is this problem where I can not find a way to use a .png image with css and then binding it with a circular motion when it comes to a halt after some time.

After that when clicked on a random place, it has to disappear and then reappear after a certain event is triggered and go through the same animation again.

I found this fiddle,https://jsfiddle.net/cshao/1kb8cm7j/1/, where everything works as expected, but the stop is tied to a click event instead of time passed and it does not answer on how to restart that event after clicked on the canvas where it should return to 0 or 360 degrees position and then rotate half a circle and then come to a halt. Code from this fiddle below--

javascript:

```
function include(arr,obj) {
return (arr.indexOf(obj) != -1);
}

var hasPaused = false;
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (hasPaused) {
    return;
  }
  if (e.target.id == "errordot") {
    var sun = document.getElementById('errorsun');
    // var classes = sun.className.split(" ");
    if (sun.className == "orbit") {
        //sun.className = "";
        sun.setAttribute('class', 'orbit paused');
        e.target.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
        hasPaused = true;
      }
     else {
        sun.setAttribute('class', 'orbit');
        e.target.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
      }
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
#errordot{
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
width:50px;
height:50px;
background:red;
border-radius:50%;
font-size:40px;
}
#errorsun{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    position:absolute;
    top:50px;
   left:50px;
}
.orbit {
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function:linear;
    -webkit-animation-name:orbit;
    -webkit-animation-duration:5s;
}
.paused {
  animation-play-state: paused;
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
}

@-webkit-keyframes orbit {
from { -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg) }
to { -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg) }
}
@-moz-keyframes orbit {
from { -moz-transform:rotate(0deg) }
to { -moz-transform:rotate(360deg) }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="errorsun">
<div id="errordot">
</div>
</div>
```

Also, the image should start moving immediately when opened, or clicked on the canvas when the image has already disappeared, move half way and then come to a halt.
Moreover, the dot in this example was made with css, as the need is a still .png or .jpg image that would perform the same way.

I tried with spritesheet animation, successfully making the image move and then circulate, but can not find a way on how to make that image stop after some time and then when clicked on the canvas, to disappear and repeat the cycle when pressed again on the canvas after the image has disappeared.

In conslusion, then the need is for a .png or .jpg image to move across the screen in an circular motion half a cricle, then come to a stop, remain there until someone presses the cavas or to any other random place, it disappears and then repeats the cycle when pressed/clicked on the canvas after the image is no longer visible. Basically it functions, click-gone, click-animation and stop, click-gone, click-animation and stop, etc.

I tried with hidden or visible in javascript by making the css class hidden. That made the image disappear, but after turned visible again, it would remain in the exact location on screen as it was before it was made hidden.

I also tried with .gif, but could not stop the thing, so it looped over and over again. Even set the number of steps that gif should have, but then it was no longer moving, as I could not make it move again.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function include(arr,obj) {
    return (arr.indexOf(obj) != -1);
}

var hasPaused = false;
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (hasPaused) {
  var sun = document.getElementById('errorsun');
  sun.removeAttribute('class');
  var errorDot =  document.getElementById('errordot');
  errorDot.removeAttribute('style');
    hasPaused = false;
    return;
  }
  if (e.target.id == "errordot") {
   var sun = document.getElementById('errorsun');
    // var classes = sun.className.split(" ");
    
    if (sun.classList.length == 0) {
          sun.setAttribute('class', 'orbit');
               e.target.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
               setTimeout(()=> {
               sun.setAttribute('class', 'orbit paused');
               e.target.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
               hasPaused = true;
                 }, 2000);
      }
    }
});
```

```css
#errordot{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background:red;
    border-radius:50%;
    font-size:40px;
}
#errorsun{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    position:absolute;
    top:50px;
    left:50px;
}
.orbit {
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function:linear;
    -webkit-animation-name:orbit;
    -webkit-animation-duration:5s;
}
.paused {
  animation-play-state: paused;
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
}

@-webkit-keyframes orbit {
from { -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg) }
to { -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg) }
}
@-moz-keyframes orbit {
from { -moz-transform:rotate(0deg) }
to { -moz-transform:rotate(360deg) }
}
```

```html
<div id="errorsun">
<div id="errordot">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, very much, your answer is utmost detailed.